# Extracting a table row with a particular attribute,using HTMLAGILITY pack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

Consider this piece of code:

```
<tr>
                                                <td valign=top class="tim_new"><a href="/stocks/company_info/pricechart.php?sc_did=MI42" class="tim_new">3M India</a></td>
                                                <td class="tim_new" valign=top><a href='/stocks/marketstats/indcomp.php?optex=NSE&indcode=Diversified' class=tim>Diversified</a></td>
```

I want to write a piece of code using HTMLAgility pack which would extract the link in the first line.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://theurl.com");
            try
            {
                var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class=\"tim_new\"]");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to insert a `foreach(var link in links)` statement/loop inside the try block, a runtime error is thrown.

Comment: if I show you my code, you would laugh out loud. Nevertheless, allow me (code in the next comment)

Comment: `a runtime error is thrown` What is the error message and stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

The code `doc.LoadHtml("http://theurl.com");` will not work. The parameter to LoadHtml should be a string containing HTML, not a URL. You must first fetch the HTML document before trying to parse it.

Once you have the document loaded, for this specific example you can use this:

```
IEnumerable<string> links = doc.DocumentNode
                               .SelectNodes("//a[@class='tim_new']")
                               .Select(n => n.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Comment: Mark, I want to extract the links specifically with class="tim_new". You see there are many links in the said html

Comment: If instead of `href` in the attributes, can I parse for `"tim_new"` ?

Comment: @Soham: I've updated my answer, but note that your problem is mostly to do with the way that you are loading the document rather than with how you are parsing it.

Comment: Yes Mark, I have taken note of that and I have changed the code. Thanks for the help. I am not sure, if my query was proper. Can you comment more on that part? 

Thanks for the piece of code.

Comment: @Sohan: Your XPath query was OK. Note that it selects the entire `td` element, not just the link. In the query in my answer I select only the `href` attribute.

Comment: Oh Okay, thanks. I needed to extract only the link. Moreover, how much time does HTMLWeb.Load() take? Does it take a lot of time? The HTML file when I save it as text it comes as around 624KB

Comment: @Soham: Actually I didn't know about the `HtmlWeb` class... thanks for teaching me something new. :) I don't know how long it takes. I would imagine that it depends mostly on your connection speed.

Comment: Hmm...Mark, one more thing,does the program close cleanly? I.e does it have to do some housekeeping?

Comment: @Soham: It's hard to say when I can't see your full program, but the code that you've posted looks fine to me. The main thing is to close any open network connections. I think HtmlWeb.Load does this for you.

Comment: Mark, thanks for this, can you suggest me some good reference from where I can read up about XPath and DOM nodes. I am finding it difficult to understand the various features of HTMLAgilityPack