# How does this XPATH query differentiate?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am kind of repeating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985029/xpath-query-htmlagilitypack-and-extracting-text) because mostly due to my own ignorance, I could not fully understand the innards.

Given this HTML snippet

```
<td valign=top class="tim_new">
  <a href="/stocks/company_info/pricechart.php?sc_did=MI42" class="tim_new">3M India</a>
</td>
<td class="tim_new" valign=top>
  <a href='/stocks/marketstats/indcomp.php?optex=NSE&indcode=Diversified' class=tim>Diversified</a>
</td>
```

How does this XPATH `//a[@class='tim_new']` differentiate between line 1 and line 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiate"?

Comment: `var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class ='tim_new']").Select(n => n.Attributes["href"].Value);`
This HTMLAgility-XPATH query is returning the first lines link only. So how does this XPATH query differentiate, as in how does it tell the difference between line1 and line 2 in the snippet? Because both the line have class="tim_new".

Answer (score 2):

Break down your XPath:

`//` - This will search anywhere in the XML for a match, instead of looking for an explicit "path".

`a` - This will match all `a` elements. Therefore your other elements (`td` in this case) will be ignored.

`[@class='tim_new']` - This will match an attribute called `class` with a vaule of `tim_new`.

So all together, your XPath will look everywhere in your input XML (HTML in this case) for an `a` element which has an attribute `class` with a value of `tim_new`.

If you wanted to match the `td` elements instead, you'd use `//td[@class='tim_new']`.

Comment: So given this logic, it follows that `//a[@class=tim]` will extract/look for lines with similar characteristics like that of second line?

Comment: @Soham: The XPath `//a[@class='tim']` will match the second `a` element in your example HTML.

Comment: Oh, so the attribute value is being matched, and not strings per se. For an example, how do you suggest I extract the hyperlinked word in the second line, here in this case its "Diversified". Mind you there are many other lines in the same XML/HTML file, with `a` element

Comment: So, at first thought, I thought //a will yield something interesting, but it will return everything in that way.

Comment: Okay, I dont know if its possible to extract that using XPATH,but .SELECT(n => n.InnerText); solved it. But would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @Soham: You could use `//a[@class='tim']/text()` to get this text.

Comment: Oh brilliant! Why didnt I think about that! Interesting, it gave me some good insight into its flexibility.